# Can class().method() and class.method() do different things?

Tags: python

I'd like to know if it's possible to have two methods in a class with the same name (or only one if it can do what I want) **but** the first method would be called on `class().method()` and the second one on `class.method()` (example below).

I tried to do it by creating a method with `@staticmethod` and a second one (with the same name) without.

Here is my example:

```py
class MyClass:
#   @potential_decorator1
    def my_function():
        print("MyClass.my_function() has been called !")

#   @potential_decorator2
    def my_function(self):
        print("Now it's MyClass().my_function() that has been called !")
```

What I tried:

```py
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def my_function():
        print("MyClass.my_function() has been called !")

    def my_function(self):
        print("Now it's MyClass().my_function() that has been called !")
```

But when I tested it:

```
>>> MyClass.my_function()
TypeError: my_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' #I'd like the 
                                                   #staticmethod to be called instead
>>> MyClass().my_function()
Now it's MyClass().my_function() that has been called !
```

By analyzing it, I understood that the "classic" method overrides the static method.

Comment: what's your end goal in doing this?

Comment: You can't define a function twice. Python will just take the second definition and run with it.